# Conference video call and video recording in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I wanted to create a conference video call app using xamarin forms. Can you please anyone send me a sample app?

I have checked the quickblox and did not find any related to xamarin forms.

Answer (score 1):

Conference calls are only available in with  enterprise solution with the usage of server-side. I think you need to contact the team for it .

Have a look at https://quickblox.com/developers/EnterpriseFeatures#Conference_video_calls. Thx

Comment: Is there any sample xamarin app?

Comment: xamarin is not yet listed in their documentation yet so i have no clue about it . As i said you can contact the quick blox team if you are using Enterprise Plan .